# Is it possible to use variable in Jinja2 default filter?

Tags: ansible

I guess it is not possible to refer to item variable when using
Jinja2 'default' filter?

Like in this example playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    users:
      - foo:
        name: "foo"
        home: /home/foo
      - bar:
        name: "bar"

  tasks:

    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.home | default('/home/{{ item.name }}') }}"
      loop: "{{ users }}"
```

If tried I get output like:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml |grep item
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'home': u'/home/foo', u'foo': None, u'name': u'foo'}) => {
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'bar': None, u'name': u'bar'}) => {
    "msg": "/home/{{ item.name }}"
```

Obviously I want "/home/bar" not "/home/{{ item.name }}".

Comment: How about this? `"{{ item.home | default('/home/' + item.name) }}"`

Comment: @nwinkler - Thanks, that worked nice, sometimes the answer is simple :D

Comment: Great, posted it as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use string concatenation in the expression, don't use nested handlebars...

```
"{{ item.home | default('/home/' + item.name) }}"
```

This adds the `item.name` variable to the static `/home` part.